# C++ Qt RegExp does not match special characters like @ or | or ^

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I am currently looking for a solution for my RegExp problem. I have worked through the docs and looked through the internet, but it almosts seems like that nobody uses RegExp - well at least, I cannot find what I am looking for.

I am currently working on a password strength checker according to the SANS institute for password policies. (http://www.sans.org/security-resources/policies/Password_Policy.pdf)

It says that a strong password contains:

> “Special” characters (e.g. @#$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>/ etc)

So I wanted to implement such into my Qt Project. The relevant code is:

```
bool specialChars = contains("[@|#|$|%|\^|&|*|(|)|_|+|\||~|-|=|\|`|{|}|\[|\]|:|\"|;|'|<|>|/]", password);
```

whereas contains is:

```
/**
 * @brief PasswordStrenghChecker::contains
 * @param needle
 * @param hay
 * @return
 */
bool PasswordStrengthChecker::contains(QString needle, QString hay)
{
    QRegExp check(needle);
    for(int i = 0; i < hay.length(); i++)
    {
        if ( check.exactMatch(hay.at(i)) )
        {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I then check the results it shows, that @ and any other character is not matched. Whats happening here ? The regex works fine for any other conditions such as:

```
bool digits = contains("\\d", password);
bool lowerCase = contains("[a-z]", password);
bool upperCase = contains("[A-Z]", password);
```

I am looking forward to your help.

Comment: Password checker... Strong passwords contain special characters. Maybe, but do you know this: http://xkcd.com/936/ Sounds convincing to me, but by far not my area of expertise.

Comment: @user2011734 hehe, nice one! Its a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to scape with backslash `\` the characters you have found problems

Comment: and don't put `|` in character classes (not more than once anyway).

Comment: I accept this anwswer, even though the correct answer after all was based on both of these answers. As the comment of Dieter:
// Sorry, I might miss some escape or have to many.
Pretty much sums it up, if the escaping is incorrect it wont work.